# Loading same page with different parameter, same function is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I'm working on a ionic app where I list some products. When I enter in the product-detail there are buttons that change their divs below from none to inline-block and from inline-block to none. This works fine.
But when I navigate to the same url but with a different parameter (another product) from the url product-detail, the buttons are not changing the divs style.

```
ngOnInit() {
        if (this.route.snapshot.data['special']) {
            this.product = this.route.snapshot.data['special'];
        }
    }
ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.closeDivs();
    }
unWrapDiv(id) {
        let div = document.getElementById(id);
        if (div.style.display === "none") {
            div.style.display = "inline-block";
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
openDetail(item) {
        this.providerService.setData(item.id, item);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('product-detail/' + item.id);
    }
```

Comment: Its not a good idea to directly manipulate the DOM when using angular...

Comment: If you need to hide or show some elements, better use ngIf or [hidden] attribute on your html elements.